# Convert millions of USD to GBP at minimal cost

Tags: foreign-exchange

I live in the UK but am due to personally receive a one-off payment of millions of dollars - representing the majority of my personal wealth - from a US-based organisation with whom I do business. The organisation has the money in dollars and has no UK presence nor UK bank accounts, but I would ultimately like to have it in GBP, since I intend to continue living in the UK. The means of payment are negotiable and both parties would like to avoid getting screwed on currency exchange fees.

It is well-documented online that doing an international wire transfer from an ordinary US bank account will result in receiving an unfavourable exchange rate plus fees, and sure enough this has occurred when I have had US-based organisations pay me via wire transfer to my GBP account in the past. However, when I have previously tried instead having organisations pay USD into a personal account I created with a currency transfer service like Currencies Direct, and then from there paying it out as GBP to my UK account, I found that even for six-figure transfers, the exchange rate available was still around 0.7% worse than the "interbank rate" (looked up via Google) at the moment of the transfer - despite currency transfer services like this marketing themselves as a better way to perform such transfers! For my 7-figure transaction, this 0.7% cut will represent a loss of tens of thousands of dollars to financial middlemen, which I would naturally like to avoid.

What can a person with lots of currency to convert but no special connections to financial institutions do to convert currency at a rate closer to the interbank rate? I can find a few services that advertise that they provide currency transfers *at* the interbank rate, like Revolut, but in all cases there are strict limits on how much money can be transferred and the services are not intended for large transfers like mine. Is eating a ~0.7% loss on every transfer like this just an unavoidable cost of doing business across countries and currencies, or is there some trick that I'm unaware of that other millionaires use when they need to convert their money between currencies - such as buying some liquid asset on some kind of exchange for dollars and then selling it for pounds?

Comment: Did you look at Revolut Premium? The cost would be negligible in your case and they explicitly advertise "exchange [...] unlimited amounts [...] with no fees". I've personally used them for large transfers, though not of the scale of millions of dollars. https://www.revolut.com/revolut-premium/. I wouldn't trust them with millions of dollars at once but if the sender is cooperating then you can move the money in smaller chunks. (This is almost an answer and maybe I'll post it as one, but as you already ruled out Revolut I want to check first.)

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica - Interesting! I hadn't considered Premium at all and didn't even know it existed; when I looked up Revolut's transfer limits, Premium wasn't mentioned on whatever page I stumbled across and instead all the information I saw was for Standard. I wonder if the "great exchange rates" they advertise on Premium are really the IBR rate, though, or if they're going to take 0.7% like the other middlemen do, or if it's somewhere in between...?

Comment: Did you ever ask a bank about cheap ways? There are even tax considerations. A couple millions is a big number for an individual, although I fail to comprehend how the majority of somebodies wealth can come from a one off payment of some business activity. I might be paranoid but still feel the need to warn that this sounds a lot like a scam.

Comment: I don't want to make it an answer because it isn't but I just can't dismiss the feeling that somebody in your projected situation would be much better and more reliably served by one of the many established private banking institutions than the advice of a random stanger over the net. :-)

Comment: You may want to consult a financial adviser specialising in high net worth individuals. They should have the answers for you.

Comment: Also, there may be tax implications on either or both sides of the pond. Make sure you are aware of the details and your obligations in that respect.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest using a large international brokerage with a presence in both the UK and the US, to a do a forex trade/spot currency conversion (plus wire transfer in/out, which should be a flat fee).

For example, [Interactive Brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/pricing/commissions-spot-currencies.php) advertises spreads as close as 0.1 PIP/basis point, and charges a commission of 0.2 basis points * size of trade. A basis point is 0.0001, so this is very very close to market rates, overall.

Comment: Ok I guess I misread... they will give priority to processing your application once the account is funded

Answer (score 4):

I think it's likely that the newer money transfer services are the best way to optimise costs, unless you are able to work some kind of special deal with a bank given the amounts involved.

For example [Revolut Premium](https://www.revolut.com/revolut-premium/) looks like a decent bet. At the time of writing, they advertise unlimited foreign exchange with no fees.

The cost of Premium, £6.99/month or £72/year would be negligible for your scenario.

Revolut [advertise that they give you the interbank rate](https://help.revolut.com/help/wealth/exchanging-money/how-much-does-it-cost-to-make-an-exchange/what-foreign-exchange-rate-will-i-get/). That said, it's not a *mid-market* rate, there is still a buy/sell spread. Right now the rate is $1.2459 versus $1.2424, which are approximately 0.15% away from a notional midpoint rate. (Don't actually exchange at weekends though, they add an extra loading then.)

You would still have to pay to receive the USD in Revolut. I believe they allow both incoming ACH and Wire transfers, with an £8 fee per wire transfer. I'm not sure about the ACH fees.

I have personal experience of using them for large transfers, though in the thousands to tens of thousands range only. I wouldn't personally trust Revolut with millions of dollars at once, but if the sender is cooperative you could do the transfers in smaller chunks.

You might also be able to use Wise - with wire transfers you can [transfer in $1mn at a time](https://wise.com/us/blog/wise-limits). Right now, they advertise that they use a mid-market rate and charge a fee of somewhere between 0.3% and 0.5% (I got different results playing with different calculators on their site so I'm guessing a bit).

Comment: 0.3% of a million dollars is still $3000 which is not a trivial amount

Answer (score 2):

I work for a large US company, who has an internal retention scheme involving "allocation" of company shares which take some years to be paid out.  Thus I get some thousand of US dollars paid into a US holding company called netfidelity every year.  There it will sit idle, until I do a withdrawal to a bank account.

However I live and work in another country, so like your situation, I need to "import" it while losing as little as reasonable.

My coworkers who did direct payments to their local accounts have been stung with "currency transaction fee" of up to 5%.   Some of us used [**wise.com**](https://wise.com/invite/u/matthewr1778) (formerly known as [**TransferWise**](https://wise.com/invite/u/matthewr1778)) and the change of currency from US to my-local cost 0.46 %

You have to set up an account with Wise first, and that takes some time because of anti-money laundering regs, involves sending photos of ID and it is verified by a human.  You also have to deposit ~$30 in to open the account but that is not a fee.

Comment: Have you asked FIdelity (or whoever is holding that account) what mechanism *they* recommend? They probably have a standard answer for that question; if not, they should be pushed to create one...

Comment: @keshlam no - fidelity is ... very corporate.  The employees are just product, they see the provider-company as the real customer, which to them it is.

Comment: I've actually found them reasonably responsive once I figure out which corner of the company I need to talk to. But that may also have been a matter of which questions I was trying to get answered.

Comment: My employer also uses Fidelity Netbenefits. I don't think they are likely to be helpful about this because their "standard" answer will be to kick off an international SWIFT transfer which is how you get ripped off.

Comment: I still wouldn't pay 0.46% of a million dollars to do the transfer... that's almost $5000!

Comment: @Andy I paid that moving a balance of around $4600 USD.   The percentage would drop on larger balances.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I may be completely off base here...

If the money was invested rather than being in cash, it would be possible to transfer management of those from the current US broker to one in the UK. The securities themselves are already owned by you; all you're doing is shifting who will handle selling them for you. (This can certainly be done between brokers within the US.)

Note that this avoids having to convert the investments into cash immediately, which could force you to take a Capital Gains Tax hit. Unfortunately, I have no idea whether either country would impose a tax on this bit of paperwork, or how taxes might have to be handled at the eventual sale. (That might make a good Question, come to think of it.)

There may be fees for transferring the investment management between brokers. If so they should be fairly small and probably are fixed sums rather than a percentage of the current value, since it's the same amount of work for the brokers to transfer 1000 shares as to transfer 1.

So a workaround *appears* to be to use the cash to invest, then transfer your portfolo management to the UK.

There *has* to be a downside of this, or folks would be moving capital between countries this way much more often. But I'm not seeing it, if so.

(As others have done, I must repeat that having a large sum of money "appear" in another country is often the first step in a scam. You may be the exception -- but the moment they start asking for your passwords or an unexpected fee appears, odds are that the money never existed and they're just trying to take *your* money. The fact that they seem to be pressuring you to move all the money *now* rather than drawing what you need as you need it scares me; creating a needless rush is also common in scams, to discourage folks from stopping to think about the situation critically.)

Comment: Who's this "they" that you're referring to asking for passwords? The company? There's no 3rd party involved based on my reading of the question, so the last paragraph is a little confusing.

Comment: The advice is true for almost anyone involved in this process, really... but in that paragraph we are assuming suspicions, so you can read it as whoever has been informing @karmamayr that this money exists and/or whoever they have been working with to claim it. If none of the red flags are raised, there's no problem. If they are, possible huge problem

Comment: It's the same amount of "work" to transfer $1,000,000 digitally as it is to transfer $1, so  don't see why that justifies robbery of $5000 on a transfer of the former!

Comment: Welcome to the real world economy, kid. NOTHING is priced by cost; everything is priced by value (what the market will bear, with competition for both vendors and customers). If it isn't worth that much to you, you are free to try to find some other solution which doesn't involve this transfer.